# FormatConditions Formula1 loses relativity after introducing second variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that applies conditional formatting on a range based on a formula. I use formula1 and R1C1-style notation to get the correct cells working. There is also a variables in the formula so that eventually the thing looks like this:

here it is working as intentional:

```
Set cond_range = Range(Cells(7, 7), Cells(7, 8))
cond_range.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(RC" & 1 & "<>"""";RC<>"""")"
```

[result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVfPc.png)

Then I try to add another variable and it just makes cell "RC" instead of the relative reference...

```
Set cond_range = Range(Cells(7, 7), Cells(7, 8))
cond_range.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(RC" & 1 & "<>"""";RC" & 2 & "<>"""")"
```

result:

[result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG4nB.png)

I've simplified it down to the core of the problem so I just replaced my variable by a direct number (1 and 2).

If anybody knows what I am doing wrong here that would be of great help! Thanks!

Comment: What is expected as `result 2`?

Comment: I would expect =AND($A7<>"";$B7<>"")

Answer (score 0):

### A1 vs R1C1

Try this:

```
Formula1:="=AND(R[0]C1" & "<>"""";R[0]C2" & "<>"""")"
```

... with the result:

```
=AND($A7<>"";$B7<>"")
```

... in `G7` and `H7`...

where the zeros in brackets `[0]` refer to the relative row and `1` and `2` refer to the absolute columns (`A` and `B`).

Comment: Thanks! This does the job - specifically when I introduce more variables in between the quotes.

I still do not understand why it does work when only one " & i & " interrupts the formula but it collapses to absolute references when I do two (ore more ) " & i "& ". But now I can proceed - thanks!

It now looks like like:

`cond_range.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(R[0]C" & i + 
j & "<>"""";R[0]C" & i - 3 & "<>"""")"`

Comment: [Here](https://powerspreadsheets.com/r1c1-formular1c1-vba/) is a nice read on relative references.